# error: invalid initializer va_list ap2 = va_arg(ap, va_list);

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, linux-from-scratch

I'm currently in chroot building LFS. I was trying to compile a legacy project called `install-log` but I get this error:

```
(lfs chroot) root:/src/install-log# make install
cc  -MMD -c -o list.o list.c
In file included from list.c:22:
list.c: In function 'fprintf_node':
list.c:145:23: error: invalid initializer
  145 |         va_list ap2 = va_arg(ap, va_list);
      |                       ^~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:55: list.o] Error 1
```

The source of the program is present on the [WayBack Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20051214084919/http://ioioio.net/devel/install-log/install-log/) and this is the program's [home page](http://install-log.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge.

I have no idea what is wrong as I'm not very technical. If someone could help, it would be appreciated!

This is the code snippet:

```
/* Prints 'node', using 'ap' as a formatting guide. */
static void fprintf_node(list_t* node, va_list ap)
{
        FILE* file = va_arg(ap, FILE*);
        char* fmt = va_arg(ap, char*);
/*line 145-->*/  va_list ap2 = va_arg(ap, va_list);

        /* An individual %! token */
        int token_cap = 8;
        int token_len = 0;
        char* token = xmalloc(token_cap);
        /* The expanded version of one %! token */
        int exp_token_cap = 8;
        int exp_token_len = 0;
        char* exp_token = xmalloc(exp_token_cap);
        /* The format string with all %!'s expanded */
        char* fmt2 = strdup(fmt);
        int fmt2_len = strlen(fmt2);
        int fmt2_cap = strlen(fmt2);
        char* fmt2_p = fmt2;
```

Comment: Put the relevant part of the code in the question. Preferably in the form of a [mre]

Comment: You can't do that — you haven't shown the code (off-site links should not have to be followed — the code should be in the question), but the code might possibly be intended to use: `va_list ap2; va_copy(ap2, ap);`.  That's a C11 feature.  Otherwise, it can use `va_start(ap, args); …use ap…; va_end(ap); va_start(ap, args); …use ap again…; va_end(ap);`.  Or it might be intended to do something else.  You can't sensibly use `va_list` as the type information to `va_arg()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i have added the code snippet

Comment: @JonathanLeffler should i try replacing it with the possiblities you gave?

Comment: Presumably the code worked on some machine at some time, but trying to copy a `va_list` from within a `va_list` is not guaranteed to work.  See the C standard [§7.16 Variable arguments `<stdarg.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16).  There's a requirement that you can form a pointer to the type by adding a `*` at the end; you can't necessarily do that with `va_list`.

Comment: We're going to need to see how this function is called — at least one call site — with the process used for setting up the arguments on display.  It may be possible to pass a pointer to the `va_list` (footnote 253).  Someone has been cruel to you.  At least I only had to deal with someone's code that assumed `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(int)` which is not the case on most 64-bit systems other than Win64.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what should i do in lay man terms, im not a programmer, just a linux enthusiast

Comment: Is "cry" an acceptable answer to "what should I do"?

Comment: Can you find a more recent (non-legacy) project that does roughly the same job as the one you're trying to resuscitate?  That may be easier.  If you must use this, we're going to have to see how this `fprintf_node()` function is called in order to start making guesses about what might work.  It is `static`; that's useful — it limits the code that must be consulted to a single file (at least initially).

Comment: The code is probably not irremediable but it isn't going to be fun working out what to do.

Comment: dunno if this will help but - 
`$ grep -E 'fprintf_node()' /mnt/lfs/src/install-log/*

/mnt/lfs/src/install-log/list.c:static void fprintf_node(list_t* node, va_list ap);

/mnt/lfs/src/install-log/list.c: proc_list_va(list, fprintf_node, file, fmt, ap);

/mnt/lfs/src/install-log/list.c:static void fprintf_node(list_t* node, va_list ap)

grep: /mnt/lfs/src/install-log/utils: Is a directory`

Comment: else ill try running another version of the program, if that fails, ill look for an alternative as you suggested

Comment: That's some contorted code.  In `fprintf_list()` (the only place it is used), the name `fprintf_node` is passed as a function pointer to another function, `proc_list_va()`.  There need to be fewer arguments in the `...` part of the functions.  Grump!

Comment: Did you ever manage to download a copy of the README file?  Both that and the contents of the CVS seem to be AWOL on the WayBack Machine (Internet Archive).

Comment: Given that the code is from 2003, it's not very surprising that modern compilers are not entirely happy with the code.  There are headers that should be included but aren't (`<ctype.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`).  There are type mismatches (`int *` where the interface requires `size_t *`).  There are assignments that are used as conditions too.  All fairly 'normal' but not currently acceptable (and I'm just using the default compiler options — not my normal fussy ones).

Comment: It looks like they've got the function `proc_list_va()` which applies a function with a signature `void (*func)(list *, va_list)` to each element of the list.  It is used in two files — `list.c` and `database.c`.  This is (IMO — with nearly two decades extra experience behind me) a mistake.  Writing two 'apply' functions for two different (sane) callback functions would be simpler, and would still work.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ In `database.c`, the callback signature would be `void (*func)(list_t *, char **, int *)`; in `list.c`, the callback signature would be `void (*func)(list _t *list, FILE *file, char *fmt, va_list ap)`.  The two 'apply' functions would each be local (`static`) to the source file (as well as the callback functions being `static`).    This would remove the problematic assignment and leave the functions more portable.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the package tries to use a generic function, `proc_list_va()` (defined in `list.c`), to apply two different functions to each element of the list (once in `list.c`, once in `database.c`).  In doing so, it contorts the code horribly.  I assume it worked with the available compilers on the test platforms when the code was released in May 2003, but it doesn't compile happily now.

It seems to me that the best fix is to use separate apply functions for the two different cases; it simplifies the code dramatically.  I renamed the driving functions to `apply_print_node()` in `list.c` and to `apply_prev_file()` in `database.c`.  I removed the declaration of `proc_list_va()` from `install-log.h`.

With the changes, the code compiles 'cleanly' under the default options for GCC 11.2.0 on a MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.6.5.  That is, the makefile uses only `-MMD` to generate dependency information:

```
cc  -MMD -c -o database.o database.c
cc  -MMD -c -o list.o list.c
```

There are no complaints from the compiler with these options.  It would be worth adding `-O` or `-O3` to the compiler command lines.  I've not dared to try my normal set of compiler options (`-O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common`).

I'm not sure what's the best way to get the information to you.  There's a 'patch' format file (series of `diff -u` outputs) for the three changed files below.  If you would like a tar-ball of the original and modified source files, contact me (see my SO profile, and include "SO 7182-0194" in the subject line).  The original versions of the files were stashed in the `Safe` subdirectory and the names have a timestamp attached recording when I downloaded them.  It kept the originals unsullied while I hacked on the code.  The primary changes are in `list.c`, `database.c` and `install-log.h` but I also made sundry other modernization changes in other files.

```
--- Safe/install-log-20220410.145707.h  2022-04-10 14:57:07.000000000 -0600
+++ install-log.h   2022-04-10 16:24:03.000000000 -0600
@@ -22,6 +22,7 @@
 #ifndef SEEN_INSTALL_LOG_H
 #define SEEN_INSTALL_LOG_H
 
+#include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include "version.h"
@@ -76,14 +77,14 @@
 extern void touch_timestamp(void);
 
 /* list.c */
+extern bool list_has_string(const list_t* list, const char* string);
 extern void add_node(list_t** node, void* data);
 extern void add_string_node(list_t** node, const char* string);
+extern void clear_list(list_t* list);
+extern void fprintf_list(FILE* file, list_t* list, char* fmt, ...);
 extern void insert_string_node(list_t* list, const char* string);
 extern void make_string_list(list_t* list, const char** string);
 extern void proc_list(list_t* list, void (*func)(list_t*));
-extern void proc_list_va(list_t* list, void (*func)(list_t*, va_list), ...);
-extern void clear_list(list_t* list);
-extern bool list_has_string(const list_t* list, const char* string);
 
 /* util.c */
 extern char* safe_sprintf(char** to, int* to_cap, char* fmt, ...);
--- Safe/config-20220410.150210.c   2022-04-10 15:02:10.000000000 -0600
+++ config.c    2022-04-10 15:34:00.000000000 -0600
@@ -19,6 +19,7 @@
  * this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple
  * Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA. */
 
+#include <ctype.h>
 #include <getopt.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
@@ -159,7 +160,7 @@
 {
    int i;
    int line_num = 0;
-   int buf_len = 256;
+   size_t buf_len = 256;
    char* buf;  /* The whole line */
    char* value;    /* After the = */
    FILE* file;
--- Safe/database-20220410.150111.c 2022-04-10 15:01:11.000000000 -0600
+++ database.c  2022-04-11 07:58:48.000000000 -0600
@@ -28,13 +28,26 @@
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include "install-log.h"
 
-static void process_prev_file(list_t* node, va_list ap);
+static void process_prev_file(list_t* node, char **bufptr, int *buflen);
+
+/* Calls 'func' on each node in 'list', passing a va_list to 'func'. */
+typedef void (*CallBack)(list_t *list, char **bufptr, int *buflen);
+
+static void apply_prev_file(list_t* list, CallBack func, char **bufptr, int *buflen)
+{
+   list = list->next;
+   while (list != NULL) {
+       list_t* next = list->next;
+       func(list, bufptr, buflen);
+       list = next;
+   }
+}
 
 /* Gets data from existing database. */
 void read_db(void)
 {
    list_t* node = &prev_files;
-   int buf_cap = 64;
+   size_t buf_cap = 64;
    struct stat statbuf;
    char* buf;
    FILE* db_file;
@@ -106,7 +119,7 @@
    clear_list(&old_files);
    clear_list(&del_files);
 
-   proc_list_va(&prev_files, process_prev_file, &fullname, &fullname_cap);
+   apply_prev_file(&prev_files, process_prev_file, &fullname, &fullname_cap);
 
    if (fullname != NULL) free(fullname);
 }
@@ -136,10 +149,8 @@
 }
 
 /* Helper for find_old_and_del_files. */
-static void process_prev_file(list_t* node, va_list ap)
+static void process_prev_file(list_t* node, char **fullname, int *fullname_cap)
 {
-   char** fullname = va_arg(ap, char**);
-   int* fullname_cap = va_arg(ap, int*);
    struct stat statbuf;
    safe_sprintf(fullname, fullname_cap, "%s/%s", root, node->data);
    
--- Safe/editor-20220410.150044.c   2022-04-10 15:00:44.000000000 -0600
+++ editor.c    2022-04-10 15:32:52.000000000 -0600
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
-#include <sys/types.h>
+#include <string.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include "install-log.h"
--- Safe/find-20220410.150021.c 2022-04-10 15:00:21.000000000 -0600
+++ find.c  2022-04-10 15:37:28.000000000 -0600
@@ -19,13 +19,13 @@
  * this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple
  * Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA. */
 
-#include <stdio.h>
-#include <sys/types.h>
-#include <sys/stat.h>
-#include <unistd.h>
 #include <dirent.h>
 #include <errno.h>
+#include <stdio.h>
+#include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
+#include <sys/stat.h>
+#include <unistd.h>
 #include "install-log.h"
 
 typedef struct dirent dirent_t;
@@ -68,7 +68,7 @@
        return;
    }
 
-   while (d = readdir(dir))
+   while ((d = readdir(dir)) != 0)
    {
        /* Skip '.' and '..' */
        if (strcmp(d->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(d->d_name, "..") == 0)
--- Safe/list-20220410.144854.c 2022-04-10 14:48:54.000000000 -0600
+++ list.c  2022-04-11 07:57:32.000000000 -0600
@@ -27,7 +27,7 @@
 
 static list_t* make_node(void* data);
 static void free_node(list_t* node);
-static void fprintf_node(list_t* node, va_list ap);
+static void fprintf_node(list_t* node, FILE *fp, char *fmt, va_list ap);
 
 /* Creates a node containing 'data' and advance *'node' to point to it. */
 void add_node(list_t** node, void* data)
@@ -82,14 +82,16 @@
 }
 
 /* Calls 'func' on each node in 'list', passing a va_list to 'func'. */
-void proc_list_va(list_t* list, void (*func)(list_t*, va_list), ...)
+typedef void (*CallBack)(list_t *list, FILE *fp, char *fmt, va_list ap);
+
+static void apply_print_node(list_t* list, FILE *fp, CallBack func, char *fmt, ...)
 {
    va_list ap;
    list = list->next;
    while (list != NULL) {
        list_t* next = list->next;
-       va_start(ap, func);
-       func(list, ap);
+       va_start(ap, fmt);
+       func(list, fp, fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        list = next;
    }
@@ -102,7 +104,7 @@
 {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
-   proc_list_va(list, fprintf_node, file, fmt, ap);
+   apply_print_node(list, file, fprintf_node, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
 }
 
@@ -138,12 +140,8 @@
 }
 
 /* Prints 'node', using 'ap' as a formatting guide. */
-static void fprintf_node(list_t* node, va_list ap)
+static void fprintf_node(list_t* node, FILE *fp, char *fmt, va_list ap)
 {
-   FILE* file = va_arg(ap, FILE*);
-   char* fmt = va_arg(ap, char*);
-   va_list ap2 = va_arg(ap, va_list);
-   
    /* An individual %! token */
    int token_cap = 8;
    int token_len = 0;
@@ -190,7 +188,7 @@
    }
 
    /* Finally, print */
-   vfprintf(file, fmt2, ap2);
+   vfprintf(fp, fmt2, ap);
 
    free(token);
    free(exp_token);
--- Safe/timestamp-20220410.145816.c    2022-04-10 14:58:16.000000000 -0600
+++ timestamp.c 2022-04-10 15:32:38.000000000 -0600
@@ -19,14 +19,14 @@
  * this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple
  * Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA. */
 
+#include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
-#include <sys/types.h> 
-#include <sys/stat.h> 
+#include <string.h>
+#include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <time.h>
-#include <utime.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
-#include <errno.h>
+#include <utime.h>
 #include "install-log.h"
 
 typedef struct stat stat_t;
```

Hmmm, it occurs to me that since the 'apply' functions are now each calling a single function, there's no need for the function pointer argument.  They could simply call the appropriate function directly.  That's a refinement you can make if you want.

I should state that I've only compiled the code; I've not attempted to run it.

I did not manage to download the README file from the WayBack Machine (Internet Archive) at http://web.archive.org/web/20051214084919/http://ioioio.net:80/devel/install-log/install-log/.  The CVS directory was likewise not available for download.